# how can install Horizon dashboard?

Tags: apt, openstack

I added Juno Openstack repository. How I can install Horizon only dashboard?
I had tried `sudo apt-get install horizon` and there is error`: E: Unable to locate package horizon.`  I had installed Horizon packages from link : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/horizon.  And all the same I have `E: Unable to locate package horizon`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Installing Horizon dashboard and configure please try this link below 
Surely this will works..
[1] http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/single-installer.guide.html 
[2] http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_14.04&p=openstack_icehouse&f=10 
[3] https://answers.launchpad.net/horizon/+question/210533

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here too: 
http://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers

Answer (score 0):

For installing Horizon Dashboard on localhost just try link below:

https://horizon-openstack-dashboard.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

It work!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here too: 
http://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: Moderators can delete any answer. Now all (4) links can help. If I will observe that link is changed, I will delete it, if moderators won't delete this earlier.